# how to redirect from xml to aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, iis-7

I am actually trying to understand why this site that I am looking at redirects from an xml file to an aspx file. So when I type in the location of the xml file it redirects to the home page which is an aspx file?? I understand you can redirect hostnames but I dont understand why an xml file redirects ? Does this make sense? In fiddler it returns a httpcode 301 when trying to load the xml file and the next line is a httpcode 200. You dont actually get to see the contents of the xml it goes straight to the aspx page.

Comment: Do you want to load XML into browser and than magically redirect (unlikely), issue 30x redirect when one requests an XML file, handle requests to XML with some handler or even something else?

Comment: Oh, it could be many things, it could be a security issue. It could be that xml files go through a handler

Comment: perhaps load up fiddler and inspect what happens when you load the xml file

Comment: in fiddler it returns a httpcode 301 when trying to load the xml file and the next line is a httpcode 200. You dont actually get to see the contents of the xml it goes straight to the aspx page

Comment: the xml does not go through an handler as far as I know

Comment: Your first and second paragraph completely contradict each other, as well as the title. What is your question again?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to not deliver the XML as an XML file. Instead, embed it on an HTML or ASPX page and use something like Alex Gorbetchev's syntax highlighter to display the XML. You can then have logic on the page to handle the redirection.

Comment: I need to keep the xml, just want to know where the redirect is possibly set in iis or somewhere else. That is my question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is only URL REWRITING.
This can be done using Global.asax file...

```
  Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

      Dim thepage As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path

      If InStr(1, thepage , "/sitemap.xml", vbTextCompare) Then
        Server.Transfer("sitemap.aspx") '' mask the redirection

        ''Response.Redirect("sitemap.aspx") '' or make the redirection
      End If

  end Sub
```